# Estimating out-of sample forecast for an ARIMA model

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, out-of-sample

I’m trying  to estimate the out-of sample forecast of an ARIMA model, I tried the code below, but it totally doesn’t work!

```
for(i in 1:83) {
   mod[i] <- arima(window(betahat[,1], start=1, end=109+i),order=c(1,0,0),include.mean=TRUE)
   pre[i] <- predict(mod[i],12)
   error[i] <- pre[i]$pred[12]-betahat[(109+i+12),1]
}
```

the data are taken monthly and I divided the data into 2 subsets, the first  composed by 109 obs and the second by 83 observations. From the code I would like to obtain the error for each 12 month forecast, so about  59 errors. In the code I probably have to add an if , the argument in [109+i+12] has to be lower than 192, but it’s not the problem.
I don’t know how to obtain each error, I would like that the outcome of the loop is the list of all the errors.
I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Here's some sample code for time-series cross-validation (or rolling out-of-sample forecasts) that might be useful: http://robjhyndman.com/researchtips/tscvexample/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the future it would help if you provided error messages, etc., but for this problem it's easy enough to fix anyway.   Just some comments before the code:

1) You don't have to subscript the model or predictions.
2) In the code below, `betahat` is a vector, not a matrix.  Your `betahat` might also be a vector, which would have caused errors in your run (hence the value of providing the error messages!)
3) Make your for-loop indices correct!

Here you go:

```
betahat <- rnorm(192)
error <- rep(0,71)
for (i in 1:71) {
   mod <- arima(window(betahat, start=1, end=109+i),order=c(1,0,0),include.mean=TRUE)
   pre <- predict(mod,12)
   error[i] <- pre$pred[12]-betahat[109+i+12]
}
```